# Mysql: is it better to split tables if possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

To make you understand my question I'll give you an example:
I have a chat web app with many rooms, let's say 5 rooms.
People can choose to stay only in one room and they choose it at login.

When they choose the room I have to retrieve the people already in the room, so I can structure my db in two ways:
each room one table with the people being records;
all the rooms in one table, people are the records and a column indicating the room they are in;

In the first case the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 'room_2' WHERE 1
```

In the second case the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM 'rooms' WHERE room = 'room_2'
```

Which is the best?
I think the only parameter to consider is performance, right?

Comment: The second one makes the most sense because then you don't have to create new tables for new chat rooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, no, because people are all 'like' objects and should therefore be in the same table.
All people and rooms in one table with a primary key on people, in this simple example. 
Table Rooms(pk_person, personName, table_id)

But I want to talk about a structure that you will want to consider as your website grows. You’ll want three tables, one for each object (chat rooms, people) and one for the relationships.

```
Chat_Rooms(pk_ChatId, ChatName, MaxOccupants, other unique attributes of a chat room)
People(pk_PersonID, FirstName, LastName, other unique attributes of a person)
Room_People_Join(pk_JoinId, fk_ChatId, fk_PersonID, EnterDateTime, ExitDateTime)
```

This is a “highly normalized” structure. Each table is a collection of like objects, the join allows for many to many relationships, and object rows are not duplicated.  So, a Person with all their attributes (name, gender, age) is never duplicated in the person table. Also, the person table never defines which chat rooms a person is in, because a person could be in one, many, none, or may have entered and exit multiple times. The same concept applies to a chat room.  A chat rooms features, such as background color, max occupants, etc. have nothing to do with people.

The Room_People_Join is the important one. This has a unique primary key for which chat rooms a person is in and when they were there.  This table grows indefinitely, but it tracks usage.  Including the relationship table is what logically normalizes your database.

So how do you  know which users are currently in chat room 1? You join your people and rooms to the join table with their respective Primary and Foreign keys in your FROM clause, ask for the columns you want in your SELECT clause, and filter for chat room 1 and people who haven’t yet left.

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, r.ChatName
FROM Room_People_Join j
    JOIN People p ON j.fk_PersonID  = p.pk_PersonID
JOIN Chat_Rooms r ON j.fk_ChatId = r.pk_ChatId
WHERE r.ExitDateTime IS NOT NULL
    AND pk_ChatId = 1
```

Sorry that’s long winded, but I extrapolated your question for database growth.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple and strongly recommended - one database table for all rooms for sure! What if you will later like to create rooms dynamically!? For sure you would not create new tables dynamically.